# Problems with accented characters

Tags: keyboard, kde, keyboard-layout, vlc, dvd

I use Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE Plasma. I have a DVD

/dev/sr0           0     0     0     - [.............] /media/sartoret/Più\040bella\040serata

When I start reading my DVD via VLC, it crashes.  No problem when I check the  "No disc menus" option when opening my disc. No problem when my DVD has NO NON ASCII characters in title. I think the problem is in the interaction between IBUS and Keyboard layout options. I cannot type accented characters: "composed typing" results in strange behaviors. I browsed the WEB; no success.

Any hint?

Comment: use "characters" app from activitys menu under utilities

Comment: My problem is NOT about typing characters. It is about crash in vlc.